# How to check if at least one checkbox is checked from list of checkboxes with it name attribute as array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a div and inside that div i have check boxes with name attribute as an array, now i want to heck if at least one check box is  checked.

```
<div id="check_lists">
  <input type="checkbox" name="usernames[]" value="1">

<input type="checkbox" name="usernames[]" value="2">

<input type="checkbox" name="usernames[]" value="3">

<input type="checkbox" name="usernames[]" value="3">

</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) with [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) and [:checked-selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

```
if($('input[name="usernames[]"]').is(':checked')){
    //at least one is checked
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `length` to find at least one check box is checked

```
 if($('#check_lists input[type=checkbox][name="usernames[]"]:checked').length){
      // at least one check box is checked 
      }
```